# Conditional stylesheet in Nuxt SSR depending on a store value

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sass, nuxt.js

I've been surfing StackOverflow and the Nuxt documentation, but I cannot get my head around this one.

So, I need to do RTL. My project is in Nuxt and we use SCSS. I'm setting the htmlAttrs to `dir="rtl"` conditionally depending on a store getter that tells me if the language is RTL or not. The requirement for this specific task is that a RTL stylesheet should be imported conditionally from the server side also if the country is RTL, so that it overrides the `main.scss` file.

Now, in `nuxtServerInit()`, I cannot set the stylesheet in the head, because the route will not direct me to the file, and, most importantly, Webpack won't compile it, as it's outside the regular flow of the application and not imported by `main.scss`, which is the stylesheet the Nuxt config is pointing to, and which contains all other styles. I realize that I could use a class and use it conditionally in components, but that is not the requirement. The `nuxt.config.js` file, in the relevant part, looks like this:

```
 css: [
    '@/assets/styles/main.scss'
  ]
```

There I obviously don't have access to the store.

What I said I tried was this:

```
 if (isRTL) {
    service.addEntryToArray('link', {
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      type: 'text/css',
      href: '../assets/styles/main.rtl.scss'
    });
  }
```

(We use a service to add things to the head)

I understand that was naive on my part, because Webpack has no say there, so there is no transpilation, and there is no actual asset, which means the route is just wrong, and even if it were right, the browser would not be able to read it.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved at a non-component level? This needs to be part of the Webpack flow, has to be added server-side, and needs to be an import --I cannot just import it regularly and use just a class (again, I'm not stubborn, I'm working on a project, and this is a requirement by the client).

If you need more information, I'll update the post, but I don't know what else to provide.